# Having troubles with pip command

Tags: python, pip

I am using Mac 10.8.5. I cloned a repository from GitHub on my local system and went into it's directory using terminal. Then I ran the following command:

```
fab setup
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/fab", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: paramiko>=1.10
```

So after this, I googled the error and saw the following article:

http://kitnew.com/pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-paramiko.html

I performed the operations that were mentioned in there and when I ran the command 'fab setup', I again got the same error message. Can somebody tell me what I am missing or what thing is going wrong?

Note: I am using all these technologies including Mac for the very first time.

Comment: What version of paramiko do you have installed? My guess is that the old version didn't get uninstalled.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: Well this might sound silly but how do I find the version of Paramiko?

Comment: Open up a Python interpreter session in your terminal (or open IDLE) and import paramiko. Then type out paramiko.__version__. It should output the version to the screen.